# Using Serverless framework on monorepo of multiple services with shared code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, monorepo

I have a pythonic serverless project on AWS, in which several services are contained in a single repository (a monorepo) which looks like:

```
/
serverless.yml
/service1
  lambda_handler.py
/service2
  lambda_handler.py
/general
  __init__.py
  utils.py
```

'general' is a package that is shared between different services, and therefore we must use a single 'serverless.yml' file at root directory (otherwise it won't be deployed).

We have two difficulties:

1. A single 'serverless.yml' may be too messy and hard to maintain, and it prevents us from using global configuration (which may be quite useful).
2. Deplyoing a single service is complicated. I guess that 'package' feature may help but I'm not quite sure how to use it right.

Any advise or best practices to use for this case?

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use individual serverless.yml files per each service. To use the shared code,

1. You can convert the code into a library and use it as a dependency and installed via a package manager for each individual service similar to a library. (This is useful since updating a version of common code won't affect the other services)
2. Keep the shared code in a different repository and use [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for individual service.

For more information, refer the article [Can we share code between microservices](https://codeburst.io/can-we-reuse-code-between-microservices-508fa4c1d06d) which I have originally written considering serverless.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The decision between single/multiple repos is not trivial but we think that mono is better in our case. In that case, what is the right way to use the shared code library with a package manager?